# How can the Org clock status modeline be improved?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Here's my Org clock modeline:

[image: Org clock modeline]

This is an Emacs frame with two windows. The task name is `Test123456789`, and appears in the modeline of the right-most window. And as you can see, is partially truncated.

Is there any way to improve it?

Some ideas:

- Move it to the bottom, left-most window
- Fix it so the task name isn't truncated
- Customise the colour, like making it white on red
- Hide the minor-mode information, and replace it with this
- Move the info to another part of the frame, perhaps a status bar at the top?
- Perhaps colour the background of the window with the active task?

Some far out ideas:

- Instead of putting this in the modeline, trigger some OS level thing, that puts some sort of watermark on the screen.

Comment: Here is a link to a good mode-line modification example:  http://amitp.blogspot.com/2011/08/emacs-custom-mode-line.html

Comment: It would be nice to put it into the Emacs header line.